# Can a wpf application developed with vs2008 be installed on windows 8?

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf application and want to make it run on a  win 8 Lenovo tablet 2(waiting for delivery).

Can I simply execute the application or I must use VS2010/2012?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the application normally in any machine in any windows version that has the relevant .Net Framework version installed.